Auto trigger function prerender Symfony LiveComponent
I have a LiveComponent with an array of prices, depending on if a checkbox is checked or not the prices should be with VAT in- or excluded.
This works nicely. The problem is:

When I check the box -> the prices are updated with VAT included (as expected).
I refresh the page
The box is still checked (as expected) -> but the prices are not with VAT anymore.

So the LiveComponent saves the state of the checkbox, but does not trigger the correct action after refresh depending on the state.
I thought I could fix it by using #[PreReRender].
<?php


#[AsLiveComponent]
class MyLiveComponent
{
    use DefaultActionTrait;
    use ComponentWithFormTrait;
    use ComponentToolsTrait;

    public function __construct(
      
    )
    {
    }

    #[LiveProp(hydrateWith: 'hydratePricings', dehydrateWith: 'dehydratePricings')]
    public array $pricings = [];

  
    #[LiveProp]
    public bool $inclVat = false;


    #[LiveAction]
    public function toggleInclVat(#[LiveArg] bool $checked): void
    {
        $this->inclVat = !$checked;

        if ($this->inclVat) {
            $this->setPricesInclVat();
        }
    }

    #[PreReRender(-1)]
    public function setVatPrices(): void
    {
        if ($this->inclVat) {
            $this->setPricesInclVat();
        }
    }

  
   
    private function setPricesInclVat(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->pricings as $pricing) {
            $pricing = $pricing * (1 + 0.21));
        }
    }
}


The function setVatPrices() is triggered but does not update the prices. Maybe because $this->prices is not set before render?

The #[PreReRender] isn't ideal in this case - it doesn't reinitialze or persist state between requests, I would argue for a mount function, which initializes properties on render better.
Also make the inclVat writeable, so you end up with something like this:
#[LiveProp(writable: true)]
public bool $inclVat = false;

public function mount(): void
{
    $this->updatePrices();
}

#[LiveAction]
public function toggleInclVat(#[LiveArg] bool $checked): void
{
    $this->inclVat = $checked;
    $this->updatePrices();
}

private function updatePrices(): void
{
    if ($this->inclVat) {
        $this->setPricesInclVat();
    } else {
        $this->setPricesExclVat();
    }
}

